# Best practice to read and write PDF received from my server

Tags: java, android

I've got a problem during the development of my Android application.

I have a web server storing some PDFs. I wanted, from my application, receive them and save them on the phone storage.

So, I used FileOutputStream and a Intent to open it, I used permissions "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", but when I propose my application to Google, they reject it because of "Scoped storage".

I don't know what's the "best practice" to do that.

Can someone help me?

Below a piece of my code

```java
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
fos.write(base64ContentOfMyFile);
fos.flush();
fos.close();

System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath() + " : " + Uri.fromFile(file));

Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(Objects.requireNonNull(getApplicationContext()),BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);

Intent intentView = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intentView.setDataAndType(uri, typeFich);
intentView.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intentView.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intentView.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
intentView.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
intentView.setDataAndType(uri
        , typeFich);
Intent intentChooser = Intent.createChooser(intentView, "Open with...");
intentChooser.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

startActivity(intentChooser);
```

Comment: Google rejected the app, not because of WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, Rejected due to the MANAGE_ALL_FILES permission which you might be using.

Comment: download your pdf file in the private folder of your app and access it, For this MANAGE_ALL_FILES permission is not required.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

If i download my PDF in the private folder off my app, Will other application be able to access it ? I need them to be used with Mail app and PDFs viewers

Comment: Wrong question as we see that you use ACTION_VIEW with FileProvider. All ready.